# Relations between P^#P, NP^#P and (CO-NP)^#P

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I was wondering if there were relation between the complexity classes
$P^{\#P}$, $NP^{\#P}$, $(Co-NP)^{\#P}$ ?(except the trivial inclusions)

I've the feeling that when taking a $NP^{\#P}$ machine, we can transfer the non-determinism inside the non determinism of the counting oracle, and thus leading to the inclusion $NP^{\#P} \subset P^{\#P}$.

Moreover I've for the same reason the feeling that $NP^{\#P} = (Co-NP)^{\#P}$, in the sense that you can take a Co-NP machine in the oracle (instead of a NP one ) and it does"t change anything in the resulting complexity class.

Comment: Were you just wondering or is this an exercise?

Comment: It is a real wondering, Yuval. (apparently I am not able to comment my post), I've no idea of the answer.

Comment: @Sn0w, you probably can't comment because you are now operating under a separate account.  If user37451 and Sn0w are both your accounts, you might want to merge these accounts: http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.  After merging them, you should be able to comment on your own question.

Comment: Have you checked the [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo)?

Comment: I just started wondering about this. It came up doing research. @Raphael: NP^#P is not mentioned in the complexity zoo. And searching for papers about #P is also quite difficult

Comment: Toda's wrote after his seminal theorem: "A more important
question is whether NP^(PP) is included in P^(PP), or whether PP^(PP) is included in P^(PP)."